# SharePoint Office 365 and TFS

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Are there any ways to integrate SharePoint office 365 site with Team Foundation Server (to display data from TFS on SharePoint). Maybe, is there a webpart or anything that can do that)?

Comment: Folks should not be so CS as to down vote with no reason given...

Answer (score 0):

No such way by default. Check the Supported SharePoint versions for TFS version:

TFS 2015:

```
 SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
 SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
```

TFS 2013

```
SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
```

TFS 2012

```
SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard, Enterprise)
Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
```

TFS 2010

```
Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard, Enterprise)
Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
```